# Improper margin formatting on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a website (templenaylor.com) that displays fine on firefox or chrome on macs, but on certain pcs displays like so:

[image]

How it should display:

[image]

I know this is somewhat a vague question without a codepen but was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before or if it is just my version of chrome. I do not have a lot of PC's to check the site on so I am asking here for input.
Thank you!

Comment: it will differ based on resolutions

Comment: ^ what he said. You simply need to set a `min-height` (say 700px) on `#header`. (On the computer that it works, just try resizing the height of the browser window and you'll see the same problem.)

Comment: Actually, I see what you're saying, based off your screenshots they're both about the same resolution, but I'm pretty certain it still just stems from a basic height issue. Performs the same on both Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: I don't think it's a resolution problem...  you can actually load the website listed in the URL bar in those screenshots (http://templenaylor.com/) and try it at different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, different pc have different length and width . for an example, small imac will display your website just fine, where else a bigger version 27inch imac have different width and size, therefor , it will react differently on screen.

You need to check your css, for an example, its a good practice to use percentage for responsive website..But at a certain situation, its a a good practice to use @ media rule. you could set your css to @1300px width(@media rule), Study on this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp regarding the @media rule. Im pretty sure this will solve your problem as i had previously face this problem with my last project. But if that doesnt solve your issue.

You might want to explore more on webkit extensions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions

i hope with these. it will solve your problem. Cheers.

Comment: "different pc" You do realize the two screenshots provided were captured on the *same* machine, right?

Comment: I dont realise it was captured on the same pc as the question regarding that wasnt really clear. But if it was captured on the same pc. The solution might be using at media and webkit. As chrome, firefox and IE will react differently on certain css styling. Also Mac renders certain elements of a webpage differently than PC . For an example , using this for at media screen and (-moz-windows-theme) for windows and @media screen and (-moz-os-version) might rectify the problem..  :)

Answer (score 0):

I viewed this website in Chrome(v56.0.2924.76) on a laptop and it produced the second screenshot (the one you want). However, I believe that the issue relates to the header background image height. You have it set to 100vh, but try 100vmax, which is relative to 1% of viewport's larger dimension. Here's the CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 100vmax;
}
```